# Leaflet zoom overridden by maxZoom

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

**Issue:**

So my issue is that maxZoom seems to over ride the zoom in Leaflet.

From the docs, `zoom` description is: `Initial map zoom.`

The code I am using is as follows.

**Code:**

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoom: 17,
    zoomControl: false
}).locate({
    setView: true,
}); // set default location to current GPS location

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
}).addTo(map);
```

**Result:**
The result is that the initial zoom is `18` instead of `17`.

**Expected Behavior:**

What I want is the max zoom to go no more than `18` but start out initially as `17`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised this topic a bit late and don't know if you already managed to fix the issue. I hit the same problem on a project I am currently working on and I found a solution by using [setZoom()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#map-setzoom) method.

On my specific case I am using Leaflet version 0.7.x and to me it was enough to concatenate the method to fitBounds() like in the example below:

```
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {
   padding: [30, 30]
}).setZoom(settings.zoom.initialZoom);
```

As I didn't find that much documentation regarding this specific issue, I post my solution here with the hope it can help anyone else should face the same problem.

Comment: Accepting this as answer. Unfortunately because of several issues (at the time) with Leaflet, we had to abandon it for our project.

Comment: No problem mate. I know my answer is quite late but I decided to post my solution anyway to just keep it as kind of reminder ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the maxzoom and minzoom to your tilelayer.
I have the starting zoom set in setView (13 there is the starting zoom).
Hope it helps a bit, because i'm not sure how it works when u get your location by gps.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([8.939, 3.541], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18,
minZoom:7,
attribution: 'OpenStreetMap'
}).addTo(map);
```

Kristjan

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `.locate()` function resets the zoom to a level that is appropriate for the supplied user location. If you don't want this, you can set a separate [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate-options) for this, too.

Comment: I have tried writing `zoom` in the `.locate()` function but this changes nothing. It should be noted that I also tried writing this in the `L.tileLayer()` method call.